# map function and not populating variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following block of code

```
var cars = $('#mypage').data('carsdata');

if (cars == null) {
    var clientId = $("input[name='ClientId']").val();
    worksheet.ajax.execute('GET','/Cars/GetData/', { clientId: clientId }, function (res) {
        if (res == "") {
            return;
        }

        cars = res.Owners.filter(function (e) {
            if (e.Email) {                        
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }).map(function (e) {                
            return { key: e.Id, label: e.Email };
        });

        console.log("1" +cars.length); // cars lenght is 3
 });


console.log("2" +cars.length); // cars is null
```

maybe this is too much code but the problem is that cars variable on last line is always null even though I have if statement where I checking null and in that case I'm populating that variable, where in

```
console.log("1" +cars.length);
```

cars length is 3, so it's not null. Why this cars.length is not replicated on

```
console.log("2" +cars.length);
```

is everything ok with this `map function` in a way that I'm correctly populating cars variable?

**Update:**

when cars is correctly loaded with data- attribute I'm getting data in following format

> [Object { key=101,  label="email@email.com"}, Object { key=22, 
>   label="email2@email.com"}, Object { key=442, 
>   label="email43@email.com"}]

Comment: What is your data?

Comment: can you provide a sample of the data which is stored in cars ?

Comment: that's out of the scope of this question, let's say that I'm getting correctly from the page using data- attribute.

Comment: will provide sample data in a min.

Comment: Your `map` is fine, the `execute` asynchrony causes the problem. Use callbacks or return a promise.

Comment: Please correct if I'm wrong but in my code example res is callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are populating `cars` inside the callback of `worksheet.ajax.execute( )`

That gets called asynchronously, so your application flux is different from what you expected, and follow this order instead:

```
var cars = $('#mypage').data('carsdata');
//1) cars is null here

if (cars == null) {
    //...        
    //2) get inside the if statement and start the ajax call
    //   cars is null here
    worksheet.ajax.execute('GET','/Cars/GetData/', { clientId: clientId },
        function (res) {
            //...
            //4) the ajax call return his value, and cars is updated
            cars = res.Owners.filter( ... )

            //5) now cars has the correct value
            console.log("1" +cars.length); // cars lenght is 3
        })
}

//3) get out of the if statement, print the console log 
//   cars is still null here
console.log("2" +cars.length); // cars is null
```

Comment: thanks for clarification, but what's the solution here?

Comment: It's an explanation of why there is no solution, you cannot set your data into cars if you still don't have it.